# IIS WebService Contention

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, websocket

I am just optimizing the WebService performance of my ASP.NET website.
The services from user's point of view feel fast enough but Stackify Retrace shows me that most WebService-Calls go to the queue for about 500ms before being executed.

The site serves only about 20-30 WCF-requests/s on a dedicated 8 core + HT machine. CPU and memory is healthy: There should be no reason at all to queue those requests.

I've noticed that queueing become worse when I started to use WebSockets more extensively. I moved a lot of WCF traffic to WebSockets, but the average execution time for the WCF-calls has increased (because of the queueing)

I've played around a lot with these settings:

- maxWorkerThreads
- minWorkerThreads
- maxIoThreads
- minFreeThreads
- minLocalRequestFreeThreads
- maxconnection
- executionTimeout

No luck. By now I learned that those are relevant mostly for .NET 2 and have intelligent defaults in .NET 4 anyways. That explains why all my meddling didn't have any effect.

Question: Are there any relevant performance counters which would help me find out why so many requests are getting queued?
Are WebSockets/WebServices using some shared resources?

Comment: Use a performance profiler or perform hang dump analysis. You have to know the exact root cause of slowness, before making any change to IIS/ASP.NET settings.

Comment: Such as? I looked at ANTS but it seems that it would profile my WCF code. I don't think it would find out when or why the call is sent to the queue in IIS.

Comment: All requests must go to the queue first, and then be picked up by worker threads. So you have to profile your code to see why it runs that slow and fails to pick up requests as quickly as possible. It's pretty easy to write bad code, so be patient while you analyze further.

Comment: WCF includes a large set of performance counters to help you gauge your application's performance. For information about WCF Performance Counters, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/performance-counters/